# Universal Law of Strong/Weak Force?

Tags: interactions, weak-interaction, strong-force

Okay, first things first, I'm very basic when it comes to the field of physics, but I'm very good at coding, and I was wondering if I could simulate an atom.

I know that in order to make such a simulation, I have to understand the mechanics of the four fundamental forces.

Gravity: 
$$\ F=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$

Electromagnetism:
$$\ F=\frac{k_eq_1q_2}{r^2}$$

But I don't know what the rules are for Strong and Weak Forces.  I'm very aware of the possibility that we don't yet know such formulas, as made clear by several sources, but I also once remember going on a website and seeing someone with a slideshow showing each of the formulas for fundamental forces, some involving summations and undefined variables, but I can't find this website anymore.  If anybody knows the formulas for Strong and or Weak interactions or has verified that these laws aren't yet solved for, please leave answers below.

Comment: Atomic dynamics is governed by the equations of quantum mechanics, none of which you have written in your post. Instead, your equations are purely classical and they are incapable of giving not even a rough description of atoms. You just can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an equation for the strong nuclear force?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8452/). See also [Do strong and weak interactions have classical force fields as their limits?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39229), [What laws (formulas) govern forces between atoms?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82067) and links therein.

Comment: Thank you.  That answered my question very well, though I will still keep this question up for a little bit longer, just in case someone brings up another equation that might come in handy. :)

Comment: You can model [interatomic or intermolecular forces](http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/MCEN/MCEN5024/Part%20two%20-%20Interatomic%20and%20intermolecular%20forces.pdf) with something like what you had in mind, but atoms are too small for the classical "interacting little planets" intuitions to be of any use. By the way, gravity is completely negligible in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

When you are speaking about the atomic scale, gravitational and weak forces have no great effect. The forces that really contribute into this process are the electric force between the nucleus and the electrons, and the strong force between neucleons in big atoms. I suggest starting with the Hydrogen atom for simplicity (1 proton 1 electron) and then moving on to bigger atoms where the interactions (several electrons, several protons and neutrons) become much more complicated (interactions between electrons need more fine structure accuracy and interaction between nucleons need to be calculated using a many body problem which is pretty complicated to be solved to get exact answers). For some simple values I suggest you take a look at this link (http://teacher.nsrl.rochester.edu/phy122/Lecture_Notes/Chapter22/Chapter22.html)

Comment: Okay, I get that there isn't any "classical" answer to this problem, but i don't really care, as long as the answer isn't "there's no answer, all particles move randomly", that's fine by me.  And even if it is "they move randomly", how randomly?  Do they move any which way, or is there some bias to this motion?  Any answer is better than "you're too stupid to understand because you only know classical physics."